# Raspberry Pi (B+): ADB is unable to detect my android device

Tags: android, usb, raspberry-pi, adb

I am trying to run ADB on my Raspberry Pi and communicate to a connected android device. The Pi is unable to consistently detect my device. When I run "adb devices" it comes back empty.
It requires a powered USB hub. Meaning if I use a powered USB hub to connect the same device to the same pi it works consistently all the time. This led me to believe maybe the USB port on the Pi is unable to power the device so I used measured the power and/or current that the device draws from the Pi and the hub and they seems to be same (I: 0.46amps and U: 5V).

Can anyone help me understand what is going on? The same device is detected on my Ubuntu desktop and Mac Pro laptop. Also, noticed that my Samsung S5 gets detected by ADB on the Pi (without powered USB).

I have tried the following so far.

1. Updated the udev rules file. Build the ADB tool for armV6 platform   and it works.
2. Updated my Raspberry Pi (packages, kernel 4.07+, and   firmware) but following the steps in:    http://stevenhickson.blogspot.com/2013/02/updating-your-raspberry-pi-packages.html
3. Run 'dmesg' on the Pi and I do see the device and its serial number
4. Running 'lsusb' does show the device with right vendor and product    ids.
5. Tried updating the '/boot/config.txt' file with    'max_usb_current=1'.
6. Tried setting the magic gpio control pin 38 by  following the steps in:    https://projects.drogon.net/testing-setting-the-usb-current-limiter-on-the-raspberry-pi-b/

Comment: Have you managed to solve your problem? I'm running into a similar situation but I don't have a powered USB hub.